# Installing the QML Package for GO-1.2 Cannot Be Found - Xubuntu

Tags: go, qml

***A Little Background:*** I am extremely new to GO and QML. The main reason I have been perusing the internet about them is because I am trying to build the Sublime Text clone Lime Text. I am on Xubuntu 13.10. I installed GO from the instructions under their 'Getting Started Section' on their website. I downloaded and unpacked the go1.2.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz tarball to my `/usr/local/` folder. I added `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin`, `export GOROOT=/usr/local/go`, `export GOBIN=/usr/local/go/bin`, and `export GOPATH=$HOME/gocode` to my .bashrc file.

I then could successfully follow the directions on the Lime Text github wiki for building and perform `go get github.com/limetext/lime/frontend/termbox`. I followed the rest of the instructions on their wiki page and everything seemed to execute sucessfully.

***My problem*** is Lime Text requires that the GO QML package be installed. So I went to their [git hub page](https://github.com/go-qml/qml) and installed all of the QT dependencies that are suggested from the ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa repository. I have already installed GO so I don't re-install GO with the `godeb` program. I then perform `go get gopkg.in/qml.v0` in my terminal. I don't get any messages to my terminal and assume that everything went fine. I then go back to the Lime Text build instructions and try to build the QML front end. I cd to `cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/limetext/lime/frontend/qml` and run the `go build` command. The output to my terminal is:

```
main.go:18:2: cannot find package "github.com/niemeyer/qml" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/pkg/github.com/niemeyer/qml (from $GOROOT)
    /home/jesse/gocode/src/github.com/niemeyer/qml (from $GOPATH)
```

I tried to use Catfish to search my whole system for the word 'niemeyer' to see if it was installed somewhere else but the search turned up nothing. I have tried running `go get gopkg.in/qml.v0` a few more times and I get the same results. I don't know if I am doing something wrong with installing a package or have some other fundamental misunderstandings about GO.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I apologize for using any incorrect terminology here as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same place where you ran `go build`, run `go get`, no parameters. It will search the code base for all dependencies and download them. If you want, you can instead do `go get -v`, where `-v` stands for verbose. It will tell you exactly what it is downloading and building.

After that you should be able to `go build` successfully.

Comment: Wow that is slick. Thank you! Would I have had to ever explicitly run `go get gopkg.in/qml.v0` or would that have installed itself when I run the `go get get`with not parameters?

Comment: `go get` with no parameters would have probably picked it up anyway. If you want, try `go get -u -v`. `-u` means update, it will print out the whole list and try to redownload everything.